# Push single file to Zeitwerk loader

Tags: ruby, glob, zeitwerk

For a Roda app, I'd like to include a single file for autoloading by Zeitwerk while ignoring all the others in that directory. The simplified layout looks like this:

```
config
  application.rb
  puma.rb
  (...)
lib
  my_class.rb
  (...)
```

To setup Zeitwerk, this would be perfect but not possible:

```rb
loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.new
loader.push_dir('lib')
loader.push_file('config/application.rb')       # <--- no such thing as push_file

if ENV['RACK_ENV'] == 'development'
  loader.enable_reloading
  loader.setup
  run ->(env) do
    loader.reload                               # <--- full reload on every request
    Application.call(env)
  end
else
  Zeitwerk::Loader.eager_load_all
  loader.setup
  run Application.freeze.app
end
```

Excluding all but `application.rb` using `loader.ignore` won't cut it neither, Ruby glob patterns don't implement negation it appears.

I could of course move `application.rb` into `lib/` (and I might have to), but I'd rather have it in `config/`. Any way to make this fly?

Comment: How does `config/application.rb` look like?

Comment: It defines `class Application`, just a pretty standard Roda app class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to answer the question, there is no way to push one single file. I might consider adding that feature, but need to think about it.

Then, in Roda, you could argue that the application class is not configuration. That class dispatches and has application logic. I'd consider moving that file out of the `config` directory for conceptual reasons, regardless.

If you totally want to keep it in that directory, you can "reload" manually in development (untested, written on the spot):

```rb
loader.reload
load "#{__dir__}/config/application.rb"
Application.call(env)
```

Point is that `load`, unlike `require`, executes always the file.

I am not familiar with Roda and it could be the case that running the file multiple times messes with internal state. If that was the case, you could remove the constant before the `load` call:

```rb
Object.send(:remove_const, :Application) if defined?(Application)
```

I've seen Roda has an `inherited` hook, but does not seem to cache subclasses in internal state.

Additionally, for production, you normally want to run `loader.setup` before `eager_load_all`, so that your application is eager loaded too.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. I agree with your conceptual argument, however, in this case the application.rb (often roda_app.rb) is stripped an only loads plugins. Everything else is autoloaded in. As much as push_file would be useful to me here, I guess it takes more than one use-case to justify the additional complexity. For now, I worked around it by putting it into config/roda/application.rb – but I might indeed refactor towards kicking it out of config altogether.

Comment: "loader.setup before eager_load_all" – thanks a lot fot the hint!!

Comment: FYI – I converted my "ad hoc cluster of code" into a proper Ruby gem which opened nice solutions to arrange the code differently and – following your advice – moved application.rb to a dir which can safely be pushed. push_file might still be useful at times, but it might just as well be an anti-pattern, at least it doesn't seem to be an easy extension of Zeitwerk.